# How to open a port to just one IP Address? (IPtables)

Tags: linux, networking, debian, mysql, iptables

I have a small server at home, and a larger rented server.
I want to use (despite the fact that it would maybe kill my Internet connection) my server at home as Database Server.
The Rented Server has a fixed IP, so how can i open the MySQL Port (3306, i believe) so that only the IP of my rented server can access the database?
I use Debian on both servers, so i would like to set this up via IPTables

//Edit: If i missed out anything, or this is a duplicate of another question, i'm sorry, i'm new to this forum... If you need any more information, ask about it, then i can provide it.

Comment: Just use the `--source` option? But really, it’ll hurt whatever application is accessing the database a lot.

Comment: could you provide an answer as a whole? As said, i'm really new to IPtables setup... btw i am aware of the possible connection problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple steps you'll have to go through to make this setup work.

- Setup a port forward on your router.
- Setup some kind of dyndns because most likely your home IP is going to change every so often.
- Setup firewall rules for your home and rented server.

  - For specific steps you will have to elaborate on your current setup for your servers. Do you already have some iptables rules in place? Otherwise you might just be fine by using a rule like `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3306 --source <serverip> -j ACCEPT`

You probably want to have a closer look at how iptables works by reading a more general tutorial. iptables has multiple queues (chains) which are by default Input, Forward and Output. [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) has a nice diagramm for this but it's quite complex. Essentially you'll most likely work with the Input and Output chains to filter traffic the way you want to. Don't forget that chains, by default, are usually set to accept all so you might run something like this `iptables -P INPUT DROP` to drop all traffic that doesn't meet a rule - BE CAREFUL it might also lock YOU out of your system. There are tools which might help you make such changes less dangerous. ;)

Comment: By "tools", are you talking about something like a webinterface?
And the firewall rule would DROP every connection attempt to the port except for the source IP?

Comment: Probably some web interfaces as well but more like `iptables-apply` which just waits for you to accept a change and reverts it after a few seconds assuming your ssh connection got bonked. The combination of those two rules would actually drop every connection that is not meant for port 3306 from that port. This includes ssh sessions and everything else. Essentially you'd either open that database connection or would have to have physical access to that computer.

Comment: Matching state is unnecessary here.

Comment: Could you tell me why? Just because you'd limit it to a single IP and you wouldn't anything bad coming from that direction? I'll edit it anyway. Oh and @ComicZockt did it help?

Comment: @Seth Even if something bad came from that direction, it would pass anyway. The state would've always matched anyway.